# How to combine IQueryable records in .net Core 6 Web API

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0, asp.net-core-6.0

I'm using .net Core 6 web API, and I've this case where I need to loop through multiple object, and each has a IQueryable result.
Then all results need to be grouped in one query. Finally the the result will be sent as paginated list.

Here's more details in the code, I will get list of ObjectA from db:

`var query = _context.ObjectA.AsQueryable();`

Now I need to get list of User. For some reason the users will have multiple records with their username, so each record represent a role:

`var rolesFromDb = await _context.User.Include(x => x.Role).Where(x => x.Username == "user").ToListAsync();`

Now I need to loop through **dynamic roles** and filter the **query**. I have 2 (or more) conditions, the the code will look like this:

```
            if (rolesFromDb.Count != 0)
            {
                var result = new List<ObjectA>();
                foreach (var item in rolesFromDb)
                {
                    if (item.Role.Level == 1)
                    {
                        var condition1 = query.Where(x => x.Level == 1);
                        result.AddRange(condition1);
                        continue;
                    }
                    if (item.Role.Level == 2)
                    {
                        var condition2 = query.Where(x => x.Level == 2);
                        result.AddRange(condition2);
                        continue;
                    }
                }
                query = result; // I need to do something like this, this is not the way to do ofc
            }
```

After this loop, I've a search filter that depends on this *query*.

In general, my main issue is I'm not able to make *query* = all filtered queries.
Thank you.

Comment: You're asking how to add filter conditions to the query, not how to add records. `query=query.Where(...);` creates a new query stores it in the original variable. In this case though, you don't need the branch at all. Just `query.Where(x => x.Level == item.Role.Level)`. If EF doesn't recognize `item.Role.Level` as a value, you can store it in a variable eg `level` and use it `query.Where(x => x.Level == level)`

Comment: On the other hand, if you want to check for a role in a list of roles, extract the role IDs/levels into a `List<int>` and use `Enumerable.Contains`, eg `Where(x=>levels.Contains(x.Level))`. This translates to `IN (@value1,@value2,...)`

Comment: No I'm not asking about filtering, I'm asking about how to combine multiple queries. I've multiple roles thus I've multiple levels not just one.

Comment: What you posted adds filters, not queries. And the actual operation is an `IN` clause. You've used several wrong terms and the code doesn't match what you ask. You need to explain the *actual* problem, not how you think it can be solved. Do you want to create a report query dynamically? Just the Where clause or the Select as well? If you have a list of roles, `Contains` is enough. What more do you need?

Comment: Maybe its my bad I didn't explain it well, I edited my question.

Comment: You keep using the wrong terms. Explain what you actually want to do, not how you think it can be done. Don't try to "simplify" or "generalize" or post examples "something like this". You can't combine queries in LINQ or SQL. There's only one query, with multiple clauses eg SELECT, FROM, WHERE. There may be subqueries, but there's still one query.

Comment: You *can* construct queries dynamically. Every LINQ operator creates a new query, using the previous one as a subquery. You *can* add `Where` or `Select` to an existing query as long as the expressions are simple, up to a point. Beyond that you need to use libraries like LinqKit to construct the expressions.

Comment: Thank you, now I've better understanding.